# Angular JS: Selenium cannot click a button by python code on mac

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a button, i can successfully find it and capture it's text. However click is not working. Can someone help.

```
<button class="yellow labeled icon button no-margin" type="button">
<div class="icon my_class"></div>
<span class="ttt">Add new student</span>
</button>
```

This works:

```
return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath').text
```

But this does not work and "no exception". Code pass but click not done.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Of-coarse invoking `.text` and `click()` relates to two different states of a *WebElement*.

Your code block `return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath').text` succeeds as the text **Add new student** gets rendered within the *HTML DOM* when you lookout for it. This doesn't guarantees that the *WebElement* is also *interactable* by that time. There is a possibility of a *JavaScript/Ajax* at work rendering the `button` at that point of time.

It is worth to mention that rendering of the text **Add new student** resembles to the expected_conditions clause of [`text_to_be_present_in_element`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element) where as **interactability (i.e. clickability)** resembles to the expected_conditions clause of [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)

### Solution

As you mentioned it's an *AngularJS* based site/element and the click is not getting executed you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set as [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath"))).click()
```

Comment: new observation...i cannot click manually once i reach that page via automation flow. This happen only when browser opens by automation tests, otherwise if i open the website manually, i can always click.

Comment: Of-coarse this sounds to be a different issue then the issue which you were facing for which you have raised the question. You can raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking it with javascript :

`element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`